# "no valid bootloader target device" when installing Fedora using anaconda

Tags: fedora, system-installation, installer-anaconda

I was trying to install fedora 21 in unallocated space along side Windows 7.
Its showing I have 261 GB free space. I mounted all the mount points correctly but the anaconda installer gives error. It says

```
no valid bootloader target device...
```

All screenshots and cam shots included.

[image]

[image]

[image]

With opensuse, I can't see the unallocated space...